# How can I resize a double pointer 2D char array by using a 3D char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, function-pointers

I am not sure how to resize a char** 2D array from a char***. The char** 2D array is passed through this resize function as seen below.

Here is said function:

```
    resize_canvas(&C, 5, 6, 5, 10, 'e');
```

This passes through the code below. It's printing out a char***, but not at the size I wanted it to be. It must be able to resize to any given size from the function above:

```
    void resize_canvas(char*** Cp, int old_width, int old_height, int new_width, int new_height, char wc){

    int height = new_height;
    int width = new_width;
    int depth = 1;

    Cp = new char**[height];

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        Cp[i] = new char*[width];

        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            Cp[i][j] = new char[depth];
            for(int z = 0; z < depth; ++z){
                Cp[i][j][z] = wc;
                cout << Cp[i][j][z];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

It is not giving me what I'm looking for. The previous char** array printed out this:

```
    // C:
    // ddddddd
    // ddddddd
    // ddddddd
    // ddddddd
    // ddddddd
    // ddddddd
```

I need it to be able to resize so it can be this later:

```
    // C:
    // ddddddeeee
    // ddddddeeee
    // ddddddeeee
    // ddddddeeee
    // ddddddeeee
```

These were my previous functions that allocated and filled the char** 2D arrays:

```
char** allocate_canvas(int width, int height){

    char **array;
    char temp = 'A';
    array = (char **)malloc(height* sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        array[i] = (char*)malloc(width* sizeof(char));
    }

    return array;

}

void wash_canvas(char** C, int width, int height, char wc){

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            C [j][i] = wc;
        }
    }

}

void deallocate_canvas(char** C, int width){

    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        free(C[i]);
        C[i] = NULL;
    }

    free(C);

}
```

Comment: In new array do you want to fill all the `old_width * old_height` elements with old `wc` i.e `d`?

Comment: @sameerkn, yes that is the goal I believe. I'll be filling the array with the char passed to `wc`. After it is resized, it must have the previous array values, along with the new char values from the resized array. I provided an example in my post. It looks like the original values remain, but the values from the resized array fill in the newly added slots.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++, you can pass references to pointers. Here's one way to implement `resize_canvas`.

```
void resize_canvas(char**& Cp,
                   int old_width, int old_height,
                   int new_width, int new_height, char wc)
{
   int height = new_height;
   int width = new_width;
   int depth = 1;

   // Allocate memory for the new array.
   char** newArray = new char*[height];
   for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
   {
      newArray[i] = new char[width];
      for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
         newArray[i][j] = wc;
      }
   }

   // Deallocate the old array.
   char** oldArray = Cp;
   for(int i = 0; i < old_height; i++)
   {
      delete [] oldArray[i];
   }
   delete [] oldArray;

   // Return the new array to the calling function.
   Cp = newArray;
}
```

Having said that, it will be better to use a class that represents `Canvas`.

```
class Canvas
{
   public:

     Canvas(int width, int height, char wc);

     void wash(char wc);

     void resize(int new_width, int new_height, char wc);

  private:

     // Private data can take different forms.
     // Best to use std::vector.
     std::vector<std::vector<char>> data;
};
```

Comment: I tried this out, and I'm getting incompatible pointer types for newArray and oldArray.

char** and char***

I tried changing pointer types around, but no luck.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I failed to write exactly what you had written. I am getting an error now, since it is incompatible with this `resize_canvas(&C, 5, 6, 5, 10, 'e');`. It's part of a coding challenge, so I can't change it.

Comment: @AlexSalinas, in that case, change the argument type from `char**& Cp` to `char*** Cp` and make couple of changes in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem stems from this:

```
Cp = new char**[height];
```

Just like any parameter passed by value, updating it will affect the local value but will not return what you've changed. Effectively what you've done is taken then address of your 2D char array from before and thrown it away, replacing it with a new *local* 2D char array. You need to assign to the memory *pointed at* by your parameter, or:

```
*Cp = new char*[height];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the necessary functions to work with, so reutilize them.

```
//assuming that resize means (new_width > old_width)  and (new_height > old_height)
void resize_canvas(char*** Cp, int old_width, int old_height, int new_width, int new_height, char wc)
{
    //char*** Cp : here Cp is address of existing 2D array.


    //[1] Allocate the new array
    char **C_new = allocate_canvas(new_width, new_height);

    //[2] if the (new_width > old_width) and (new_height > old_height) then fill old elements with corresponding 'Cp[i][j]' and all the extra elements with 'wc'.

    int i, j;

    char **C_old = *Cp;  // now 'C_old' will point to you existing 2D array.

    //filling old elements
    for(i = 0; i < old_height; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < old_width; ++j)
        {
            C_new[i][j] = C_old[i][j];
        }
    }

    //[3] Deallocate the existing array
    deallocate_canvas(C_old, old_width);

    //[4] assign new array to old array
    *Cp = C_new;

    //filling new elements
    for(; i < new_height; ++i)
    {
        for(; j < new_width; ++j)
        {
            C_new[i][j]= wc;            
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    //check the array by printing
    cout << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < new_height; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < new_width; ++j)
        {
            cout << C_new[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```